# How to get next Page of ADF Pipeline run details using continuation_token in Azure Data Factory - Databricks?

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am using

> adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(resourceGroupName,
> factoryName, filter_parameters)

method of **azure.mgmt.datafactory.DataFactoryManagementClient** package to fetch ADF Pipeline Run details.

The response of above function returns 100 pipeline run records at once. Along with the response, it returns **continuation_token** which, I believe, is supposed to be used to fetch next set/page of records.

I am not sure which function to be used for this. I tried using **azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.PipelineRun()** function (trial and error) to see if that satisfies the requirement. Unfortunately, it doesn't. MS Documentation is also very abstract to understand.

So, which function in Azure's Python SDK can be used to fetch next page of run records?

Comment: Can you share the response you see

Comment: Do you want to get the all the run details or filter out any specific between time intervals or based on RunID

Comment: I want to fetch all run details within a timeframe.

Comment: you can set appropriate values for `last_updated_after` and `last_updated_before` in PipelineRunFilterParameters

Comment: Yes.. Did that already.. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential 


subscription_id = "b83c1wd3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2b83a074c23f"
rg_name = "My-rg"
df_name = "ktestadf"

tenant_id = "12f978bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47"
client_id = "a71ad3ca-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-af0c2a3fdae1"
client_secret = "Nym7Q~j5YMyxxxxxx3tAk879y9vLrxAQqaI8n"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
tenant_id=tenant_id ,
client_id=client_id ,
client_secret=client_secret)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient( credential=credential,
subscription_id=subscription_id)

pipe_run = []
dsb = datetime.now()
dsa = dsb - timedelta(hours = 24)
filter_params = RunFilterParameters(last_updated_after=dsa, last_updated_before=dsb)
pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(resource_group_name=rg_name, factory_name=df_name, filter_parameters = filter_params)
pipe_run.append(pipeline_runs.value)
while (pipeline_runs.continuation_token):
   filter_params = RunFilterParameters(last_updated_after=dsa, last_updated_before=dsb,continuation_token = pipeline_runs.continuation_token)
   pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(
   resource_group_name=rg_name, factory_name=df_name, filter_parameters=filter_params)
   pipe_run.append(pipeline_runs.value)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You get the `continuation_token` when you have the next page of results, if any remaining results exist, null otherwise.

Here is an example of its usage, however I currently don't have enough pipeline runs to show the token itself.

[image]

Now in your case, you have received one, so here is how you can use it.

Considering `pipeline_runs` is holding the results, `pipeline_runs.continuation_token` is what we need to get and pass back in another request to get the next page.

Add a simple loop, say a `While` checking for `pipeline_runs.continuation_token` exists and requesting next page until the value for token returned is `Null` - end of the result.

[image]

Complete working implementation:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential 


subscription_id = "b83c1wd3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2b83a074c23f"
rg_name = "My-rg"
df_name = "ktestadf"

tenant_id = "12f978bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47"
client_id = "a71ad3ca-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-af0c2a3fdae1"
client_secret = "Nym7Q~j5YMyxxxxxx3tAk879y9vLrxAQqaI8n"

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret, tenant=tenant_id)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

filter_params = PipelineRunFilterParameters(last_updated_after=datetime.now() - timedelta(30), last_updated_before=datetime.now() + timedelta(1))
pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(resource_group_name=rg_name, factory_name=df_name, filter_parameters = filter_params)


for pipeline_run in pipeline_runs.value:

    print(pipeline_run)

while (pipeline_runs.continuation_token):

    pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(
    resource_group_name=rg_name, factory_name=df_name, filter_parameters=filter_params, continuation_token = pipeline_runs.continuation_token)
    print(pipeline_runs.value)
```

You can optionally not print the earlier call `pipeline_runs` in `for` loop, I have them just show in code for reference.

Comment: I tried using mentioned approach, seems that continuation_token is not a valid argument in **query_by_factory()**. 
I am getting below error - 
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'continuation_token'

Comment: Is it working at your end? If yes then pls let me know what version you have of **azure-mgmt-datafactory** package installed.

Comment: past last week I lost some of the pipeline run logs and don't have enough to get `continuation_token`, but I have azure-mgmt-datafactory-2.0.0   I get `continuation_token: None` now

Comment: Can you try with azure-mgmt-datafactory 0.6.0

Comment: 0.6.0 doesnt have other functions in it. - Tried

Comment: As per mentioned here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/21879#issuecomment-979356245), continuation_token should be passed into **RunFilterParameters** instead