# Querying Pipeline runs from Azure Data Factory using Azure Databricks Spark Python got unexpected keyword argument 'continuation_token'

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm trying to query the pipeline runs from Azure Data Factory using Azure Databricks, and I found that this thread is exactly what I need.

[How to get next Page of ADF Pipeline run details using continuation_token in Azure Data Factory - Databricks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629034/how-to-get-next-page-of-adf-pipeline-run-details-using-continuation-token-in-azu)

Following the instruction from Answer 1, I got the same error message:

`request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'continuation_token'`

Is the argument's name changed?

```
pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(resource_group_name=rg_name, 
                                                              factory_name=df_name, 
                                                              filter_parameters=filter_params) 
while pipeline_runs.continuation_token:
    
    print(len(pipeline_runs.value))

    pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(resource_group_name=rg_name, 
                                                              factory_name=df_name, 
                                                              filter_parameters=filter_params, 
                                                              continuation_token=pipeline_runs.continuation_token)
```

Comment: thanks. I did try and get another error:
query_by_factory() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Comment: I basically want to fetch the pipeline runs more than first 100 records. Not sure if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

FiltersParam=models.RunFilterParameters(last_updated_after=last_updated_after,last_updated_before=last_updated_before,continuation_token=listaPipeline.continuation_token)
page2=adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(resource_group_name=resource_group_name,factory_name=factory_name,filter_parameters=FiltersParam )